# ¿Cuál es el equivalente de EXCEPT en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

```
select e.id_empleado, e.fechaRegistro,atv.nombreTipoVialidad, e.calle, e.numeroInt, e.numExt,
e.cp, es.Nombre, m.Nombre, e.localidad, e.tel, e.tel2, e.tel3,atp.nombreTipoParentesco,e.nombreContacto, e.correo, e.fecha_ingreso,e.nombre,e.apellidoP,e.apellidoM
from empleado as e, Estados as es, Municipios as m, alta_tipoVialidad as atv, alta_tipoParentesco as atp
where e.estado=es.Id_Estado and e.municipio=m.Id_Municipio and atv.id_tipoVialidad = e.TipoVialidad and atp.id_tipoParentesco = e.parentesco
EXCEPT
select e.id_empleado, e.fechaRegistro,atv.nombreTipoVialidad, e.calle, e.numeroInt, e.numExt,
e.cp, es.Nombre, m.Nombre, e.localidad, e.tel, e.tel2, e.tel3,atp.nombreTipoParentesco,e.nombreContacto, e.correo, e.fecha_ingreso,e.nombre,e.apellidoP,e.apellidoM
from ArchivoMuerto_empleado as e, Estados as es, Municipios as m, alta_tipoVialidad as atv, alta_tipoParentesco as atp
where e.estado=es.Id_Estado and e.municipio=m.Id_Municipio and atv.id_tipoVialidad = e.TipoVialidad and atp.id_tipoParentesco = e.parentesco
```

Unión de dos tablas, mostrar los registros de la primera que no estén en la segunda, utilice not in y no deja, utilice left join y tampoco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes intentar emplear `NOT EXISTS`

```
select e.id_empleado, e.fechaRegistro,atv.nombreTipoVialidad, e.calle, e.numeroInt, e.numExt,
e.cp, es.Nombre, m.Nombre, e.localidad, e.tel, e.tel2, e.tel3,atp.nombreTipoParentesco,e.nombreContacto, e.correo, e.fecha_ingreso,e.nombre,e.apellidoP,e.apellidoM
from empleado as e, Estados as es, Municipios as m, alta_tipoVialidad as atv, alta_tipoParentesco as atp
where e.estado=es.Id_Estado and e.municipio=m.Id_Municipio and atv.id_tipoVialidad = e.TipoVialidad and atp.id_tipoParentesco = e.parentesco
 and NOT EXISTS
(select e.id_empleado, e.fechaRegistro,atv.nombreTipoVialidad, e.calle, e.numeroInt, e.numExt,
e.cp, es.Nombre, m.Nombre, e.localidad, e.tel, e.tel2, e.tel3,atp.nombreTipoParentesco,e.nombreContacto, e.correo, e.fecha_ingreso,e.nombre,e.apellidoP,e.apellidoM
from ArchivoMuerto_empleado as e, Estados as es, Municipios as m, alta_tipoVialidad as atv, alta_tipoParentesco as atp
where e.estado=es.Id_Estado and e.municipio=m.Id_Municipio and atv.id_tipoVialidad = e.TipoVialidad and atp.id_tipoParentesco = e.parentesco);
```

Comment: Gracias, ahora la consulta no me devuelve ningún registro en mysql , lo cual en SQL si me mostraba registros

Comment: Has tenido la mala fortuna de tener todos los empleados muertos...

Comment: Después de analizar la consulta hice un cambio y quedo con el NOT EXISTS gracias

Comment: Si te ha servido no olvides marcarla como correcta ;)

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas similar es NOT IN

```
select e.id_empleado, e.fechaRegistro,atv.nombreTipoVialidad, e.calle, e.numeroInt, e.numExt,
e.cp, es.Nombre, m.Nombre, e.localidad, e.tel, e.tel2, e.tel3,atp.nombreTipoParentesco,e.nombreContacto, e.correo, e.fecha_ingreso,e.nombre,e.apellidoP,e.apellidoM
from empleado as e, Estados as es, Municipios as m, alta_tipoVialidad as atv, alta_tipoParentesco as atp
where e.estado=es.Id_Estado and e.municipio=m.Id_Municipio and atv.id_tipoVialidad = e.TipoVialidad and atp.id_tipoParentesco = e.parentesco
NOT IN (
select e.id_empleado, e.fechaRegistro,atv.nombreTipoVialidad, e.calle, e.numeroInt, e.numExt,
e.cp, es.Nombre, m.Nombre, e.localidad, e.tel, e.tel2, e.tel3,atp.nombreTipoParentesco,e.nombreContacto, e.correo, e.fecha_ingreso,e.nombre,e.apellidoP,e.apellidoM
from ArchivoMuerto_empleado as e, Estados as es, Municipios as m, alta_tipoVialidad as atv, alta_tipoParentesco as atp
where e.estado=es.Id_Estado and e.municipio=m.Id_Municipio and atv.id_tipoVialidad = e.TipoVialidad and atp.id_tipoParentesco = e.parentesco
)
```

DOC: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/not-in.php

Comment: ¿Funciona esa sintaxis?

Comment: Yo la vi en la documetacion de MYSQL https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/non-typed-operators.html ,espero que sea de ayuda xd. si no lo es ya me comentareis.

Comment: A lo que voy es que falta la expresión antes de `NOT IN`. (...)`WHERE` _¿cuáles campos?_ `NOT IN`(...)

Comment: Lo implemente y me daba error, ya no busque a detalle el error, lo intente con NOT EXIST y después de analizar la consulta hice un cambio y quedo

Comment: E visto consultas similares a esto con NOT IN y pense que cuadraba con su problema :c  SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.principal NOT IN (SELECT principal FROM table2)